# IIS Express trust self-signed SSL certificate pressed NO

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10, iis-express

I was trying to run for the first time my localhost from Visual Studio 2019 and Windows asked me:

[image]

I accidentally pressed NO, so now I can't see my site.
I checked different suggestions offered here, in stack overflow, but didn't work.

I tried going to Add/Remove Programs and choosing the "Repair" option on IIS Express.

Also:
`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`

`IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:urlToYourSite -UseSelfSigned`

None of them worked.

Hope anyone can give me a hand.

Thanks.

Solved:

I have deleted both, IIS Express 10 and Visual Studio and reinstall and that fixed the issue.

Comment: You can drop that certificate to your trust CA store, or simply use a tool like Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate

Comment: Also check at serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of tests to try to restore your problem, but all failed. Even if I click no every time like you do, it will still pop up the next time I run it again. When it finally no longer pops up, the application can still run, but with http instead of https. Fortunately, I finally reproduced your problem and found the following solution.

1. In control panel->Uninstall or change a program, make IIS express repair. If repair doesn’t work. Just uninstall it and install it again.

[image]

2. Open Win+R ->enter %userprofile% -> Documents ->IIS Express, then delete all folders. Open your project in visual studio. Right click solution and clean it.

[image]

Both of these method worked while I tested. You can try them. If them still useless, please re-install visual studio.

Comment: Before reading this solution, I had fixed it by reinstalling IIS Express and Visual Studio as you suggest. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If your porblem has been solved, please mark the correct answer so that can help others with similar problems